# Troubleshooting noise pickup near AC motors

Tags: connector, noise, emi-filtering

I have a 2-layer PCB with ADC communicating using SPI. This board is to be used with a National Instruments (NI, LabVIEW) FPGA, with a clock rate up to approximately 600kHz (higher would be nice, but this is the immediate requirement).

The board will be used near a pair of moderate-sized AC motors. When the motors are not powered, everything works fine. Once the motors are powered, I observe large amounts of electrical noise on just about everything. The communication breaks down and the data output is junk.

In case this information is useful, holding a BNC cable with two clips in the air shows voltage oscillations on the order of 500mV pk-pk; clipping these together takes it down to ~10mV pk-pk when observed using an oscilloscope.

The cabling in use is 28 AWG, 10 core (5 twisted pairs). 8 wires are signals, with a pair used for +15V and Gnd connections. Logic levels are 3.3V on the other lines. The twisted pairs aren't related, although I aimed to put the two highest frequency lines (SCLK, D_Out) with the slowest changing (essentially DC) lines to try and mitigate cross-talk.

The shields of the cabling are connected to the ground of the PCB and disconnected at the instrument end. Should this be reversed? (does it matter?) It's my understanding connecting both ends might/would lead to ground loops - is this correct, or did I completely misunderstand the principle here?

The 8 signal lines are connected to BNC lines, but the shields of the BNC cables are floating. The instrumentation specifies/expects a 50 Ohm cable. http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/374614a_02.pdf

How much should I be concerned about load mismatch at these frequencies? What can I do to mitigate this issue?

What should I be doing with cable grounds, connections and terminations to avoid being overwhelmed by EMI/noise?

Edit for basic drawing (even though there are 4 inputs available on the PCB for +ve, -ve PS, only two wires are available, so just one ground connection. The other can be used to connect the shield if desired):
[image]

Comment: `shields of the BNC cables are floating` why are they not connected? ... what happens if you ground them?

Comment: How are the motor cases tied to GND? How are the motor power leads filtered to the cases?

Comment: I don't know what I'd connect them to - if I connect them together, or to the chassis ground of the DAQ modules, then there's no visible change. If I connect them to the PS ground, then the data stream stops - I expect because the reference voltage changes and the logic levels don't match properly. The PS ground is via the wall supply, and the chassis for the DAQ (and its backplane/module reference, as I understand) is also via a wall supply ground. Upon closer inspection, these aren't directly the same supply, so I'm going to change that and recheck behaviour.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf The motors are 3 phases + ground in the cables to a controller, and the controller is wired to a breaker on the wall. As far as I can determine via our facilities section, the ground that I'm connecting our instrumentation to is the same as the ground that's being used for the controller, although measurements suggest this might not be true...

Comment: the BNC cables do not have 50 Ohm impedance if the shields are not connected .... maybe try connecting one of the BNC cables directly to an oscilloscope just to see the signal that is being transmitted

Comment: How many of your wires are GND? Next time, allocate one twisted pair for each signal. One of the wires in the pair will be GND and the other will be signal. And ground all shields at both ends. Including BNC shields. Don't think of the BNC shields as shields. The outer conductor is a current carrying conductor just like the inner conductor. They are both absolutely required.

Comment: Are the motors merely nearby? Or is your system directly connected to the motor controller somehow? A question like this should have a block diagram or at least a wiring diagram listing all conductors and what they are. And a picture would be good, too.

Comment: @mkeith - only one. I'm a little constrained in space for the wire (it has to pass through a few narrow holes) but if I redesign the board I'll see if I can find a suitable cable with a few more pairs and get at least the higher frequency lines in individual twisted pairs. As to the BNC cables - I know the outer shield/mesh forms the negative half of the signal but am uncertain what I can attach it to. Connecting all of the 'shields' to the PS negative side seems to be an improvement. I'll work on a pseudo-diagram.

Comment: @jsotola - Right. The impedances of the cables could be anything. I'm unsure how much of a problem this is, given that the hardware system expects/is designed to work with 50 Ohms.

Comment: Do the BNC cables to to a connector? Does that connector have a GND pin? That is where the shields should go.

Comment: @mkeith, oscilloscope probe connectors are BNC, the connector shell is the ground and should be connected to the shield and there is one center pin that carries the signal .... almost the same as coaxial TV RF cables, but with a bayonet connector instead of screw type connector

Comment: @chrisb2244, you do not seem to have signal return path for the 8 modules in the lower right corner of the diagram .... the coax cables should go from the NI9402 to the input of your board .... the cables should not be connected to anything else in between

Comment: @jsotola The coax cables currently come from the NI9402 (where they are real coax cables) and then are basically cut into two parts, the inner section, which is wired to the board, and the outer section (shield) which is connected to the same wire as the power supply negative, or ground value. I guess ideally, these would be wired to each half of a twisted pair, and wired all the way to the board's ground, but I have too few wires in my current design and so they are all shorted together at the supply end (rather than the board end). Not sure how much of a problem this is.

Comment: Coax is better than twisted pair for avoiding noise pickup. But the shield/ground needs to be connected on both ends to the ground plane of the PCB.