# ADC Circuit Review

Tags: pcb-design, adc, circuit-design, design

I'm building a PCB centered around an AD7608 ([datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7608.pdf)) with an ADG714 octal switch ([datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG714_715.pdf)) to minimize the number of wires required.

I seem to be having sporadic problems (e.g. odd levels on capacitors, board fails when switching certain lines and requires power cycle) and wondered if I was doing anything horrifically wrong (in particular around the capacitors, but also more generally).

I don't have any power protection/ESD circuitry on the board, but the board is powered by a Texio PW24-1.5AQ power supply ([catalog page](http://www.texio.co.jp/uploads/PW-A_ce3.pdf),[manual](http://www.texio.co.jp/uploads/PW-A_B71-0014-11_E.pdf)). Is this something I should consider a problem? The TVS1400 by TI, or the GSOT15C by Vishay both look almost promising, but I'm not sure if they will help anything (especially because the maximum clamp is over 20V, which is the maximum allowed voltage to the power supplies, [LT1461-{3.3,5}](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1461fb.pdf)).

Schematics as images:
[image: Overview and top-level sheet]
[image: ADC sheet]
[image: Power reference sheet]
[image: Pulldown sheet]

Layouts as image. Please let me know if it's not clear, or hiding something important. The nets aren't shown, which is unfortunate. I'll edit it if I manage to get an image out of KiCAD that shows net labelling.
[image: layout - no mirroring on back side]

Following on from a discussion about noise and connectors here: [Troubleshooting noise pickup near AC motors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377375/troubleshooting-noise-pickup-near-ac-motors?noredirect=1#comment916134_377375) I've added an additional connector for more ground cable availability, and used [adaptors of this style](https://www.elliottelectronicsupply.com/bnc-male-connector-to-twisted-pair-cable.html) for the end BNC connectors. I still don't quite have pairs for each connection, due to cabling restrictions (outer diameter limit) but it's at least closer now.

Comment: Are you familiar with CMOS latchup causes?  Routine issue to avoid applying signal voltages higher than Vdd

Comment: Reading the wikipedia page on [latchup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up) makes that look pretty likely as a cause. Unfortunately, I don't understand if it suggests anything I can do (it looks more low level, internal to ICs). The AD7608 claims transient currents of less than 100mA won't cause SCR latchup. The ADG714 makes no mention of latchup in the datasheet.

Comment: Looking through various white-papers/application notes on latchup now. If there are any particularly noteworthy references, please let me know.

Comment: Are there any voltages present on signals before IC supply is applied as per IC specs Absolute Max.? This must not occur.  I did not try to comprehend all your interface descriptions.

Comment: I think it's possible that I'm not obeying the sequencing requirements for the TS12A switch. I'm looking into using the LM3880 IC to sequence the startup of that chip, which is then fed to the ADC. Whilst checking this, I'll also check the ordering of power supplies to the ADC.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to find is a *failure mechanism* so solutions can be found to solve the problem. The hard part about solving intermittent problems is they can be hard to track down and find the root cause. It would probably be near impossible to find the source of the error only by mulling over the schematics and board layout, unless there was a blatant error. The only way out of these situations are by much testing.

The first thing I do with any design is check the power, make sure the power is clean, put a scope on it and set it to trigger above and below the noise of the typical Vcc voltage. If your seeing drops below the recommended voltage limits even for a few us there is a problem. If you are seeing spikes this is a problem. Make sure you place the ground of the oscilloscope in appropriate places as ground is not the same voltage everywhere. Next to the processor and next to the power input point are good starting ground references.

What are the circumstances of the point of failure? If your debugging does it fail at the same point every time? Is it a software error? Do the failures coincide with an event on your board? or are they random?

Use the debugger to your advantage, see if the errors are deterministic or random. Is the ADC latching up or the processor? Do the latchups occor only when external signals are monitored? Take the board and run it with only the power attached, if it runs for hours without error and the external cables are attached to the ADC then it might be the signals interfering with the ADC.

There are many other tests that can be preformed, find the situations that remote failure, once you have eliminated the most of the things that could cause the failure, you'll get closer to finding the root cause of the failure. And if you find the root cause, you can change your design and eliminate it.

Good luck

Comment: Using the current draw on the power supply as a measure of error, typically switching the Range pin (switch 3) high leads to high current draw (~50-60mA, when 20mA is the expected draw when operating). This remains the same even if the SHUTDOWN pin is low, when the draw should be ~uA for range low and ~5mA for range high.
When the board is initially powered, it sometimes doesn't reach the full voltage immediately - this I expect is a problem with the FPGA code that controls the board and is perhaps related to the switches not taking a valid state.

Comment: If the board has normal power draw, sometimes just waiting is enough to cause it to start drawing more power. I expect this is related to a fabrication problem in this specific board, but the other problems are perhaps more related to a problem with my understanding of the circuitry/requirements to make a reliable board.

Comment: Current is not a good indicator of a problem voltage is